# How to replace a string to a variable

Tags: python

I do a journal program, and have I have some teachers, who written as dictionaries. 
For example:

```
Joshua_Danice = {'first_name': 'Joshua', 'last_name': 'Danice',
            'supervision': ['9K', '8A', '9B'],
            'subjects': ['biology, chemistry']}
```

When you try to go in my program, you should print your first name and last one. It is writing itself into a variable "teacher":

```
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.teacher = str(self.first_name + "_" + self.last_name)
```

So we have

> self.teacher = "Joshua_Danice"

I want to replace that string to the variable, so I can use "Joshua_Danice" string as dictionary, and use keys from this one.

Comment: What's the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a `teachers` dictionary, which maps the name of the teacher, such as `"Joshua_Danice"` to the dictionary you post above, e.g.

```
teachers = {"Joshua_Danice":
    {'first_name': 'Joshua', 'last_name': 'Danice',
     'supervision': ['9K', '8A', '9B'],
     'subjects': ['biology, chemistry']}
}
```

Then retrieve the inner dictionary using:

```
teachers["Joshua_Danice"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is not advised to use `globals()` to check and update the variables of the class, still this might be a hack for you :

```
Joshua_Danice = {'first_name': 'Joshua', 'last_name': 'Danice',
            'supervision': ['9K', '8A', '9B'],
            'subjects': ['biology, chemistry']}

class Whatever():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.teacher = str(self.first_name + "_" + self.last_name)
        if self.teacher in globals():
            self.__dict__.update(globals()[self.teacher])
```

A better practice would surely be what dspencer suggested.